# Can I replace one door with another of almost exactly the same size?

Tags: doors

I have:

- A busted door, 79 3/4" tall, 36" wide, and 1 3/4" thick, serving as the front door of an outdoor shed. Some of the wood has rotted and a panel has fallen off, and the door needs to be replaced.
- An interior door, 80" tall, 35 3/4" wide, and 1 3/8" thick. The door is in good condition; I unscrewed it from a doorway where I prefer not to have a door.

My question is:

- if it is likely to be possible (and wise) to replace the busted door with the good door, since they are *almost* the same size;
- if I can reasonably DIY this as a beginner, or if it would be wiser to hire a contractor?

Comment: Is the interior door a hollow core? (Ie, is it really light?)

Comment: It would fit (after you trimmed a bit off the top and/or bottom), but, as stated by others, an interior door is a poor choice for one exposed to the weather.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate It's quite heavy, so I assume not.

Answer (score 2):

An interior door is not made for the outdoors, so it's lifetime is quite limited.

Will need to cut 1/4 inch off the top or bottom for it to fit.

Will to add 1/4 inch to the door side or make the door frame smaller.

Being thinner will make it look a bit odd.

With it being an outdoor shed, it will depend on you how good you want it to look, or just have a door there.

Comment: Given that it’s a solid core door, I’d use a ton of spar varnish on all the edges. If it opens out from the shed, you won’t notice the thickness, though you will have to move the stop on the strike side. I’d say go for it.